# Spring WS Client — Authentication with Server and Client Certificates

Tags: web-services, ssl, soap, keystore, spring-ws

I need to be able to do a "client cert" authentication for a SOAP service.

I'm using Spring WS. I have: a `my.key`, a `myCA.pem`, and a `myClient.crt`.

This is my relevant Java piece of code (I know it's still messy but I'm just trying *to get it to work* first):

```
public TheResponse doIt(TheRequest request) {
  log.info("Sending request...");
  try {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/keystore.jks"));
    KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keyStore.load(is, "keystore!passwd".toCharArray());
    is.close();
    KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, keyStorePassword.toCharArray());

    InputStream is1 = new FileInputStream(new File("src/main/resources/truststore.jks"));
    KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    trustStore.load(is1, "truststore!passwd".toCharArray());
    is1.close();
    TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    trustManagerFactory.init(trustStore);

    HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
    messageSender.setKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers());
    messageSender.setTrustManagers(trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers());
    setMessageSender(messageSender);

    return (TheResponse) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request,
        new SoapActionCallback("https://domain/tld/icc/SomePathDownTheLine"));
  } catch (Throwable e) {
    log.error("Sh*t didn't work due to:", e);
    throw new GatewayConnectionException(String.format("Unexpected error while sending request [%s]", e.getMessage()));
  }
}
```

This is how I'm building the trust- and key- stores:

```
# KeyStore
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -in myClient.crt -inkey my.key -out keystore.p12 -name my_key -CAfile myCA.pem -caname root

$ keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass keystore!passwd -destkeypass keystore!passwd -destkeystore keystore.jks \
  -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass keystore!passwd -alias my_key

# Trustore (using truststore!passwd)
$ keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias my_ca -file myCA.pem -keystore truststore.jks

$ keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias my_cc -file myClient.crt -keystore truststore.jks
```

...and these are the verification steps:

```
$ keytool -list -keystore keystore.jks -storepass ********

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 1 entry

my_key, Oct 17, 2017, PrivateKeyEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 1A:9D:6A:65:. . .:E6:C1:90

$ keytool -list -keystore truststore.jks -storepass ********

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 2 entries

my_cc, Oct 17, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 1A:9D:6A:65:. . .:E6:C1:90
my_ca, Oct 17, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
Certificate fingerprint (SHA1): 36:82:F7:AB:. . .:70:B2:6C
```

...but still, whenever I request the SOAP action I'm getting back an HTTP 401 (Unauthorized) — `org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized [401]`.

Any clue(s)? By the way, I'm pretty much following [this](http://zoltanaltfatter.com/2016/04/30/soap-over-https-with-client-certificate-authentication/) guide. I'm not very familiar with SSL certificates and all that stuff.

---

**UPDATE**

The SSL handshake is working correctly. I can see how it works by setting the `-Djavax.net.debug=all` VM option. What's happening now is that, regardless all of this security, the server also needs a username and password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was all OK. Eventually, the reason for the `HTTP 401 (Unauthorized)` was because the service required `Basic auth` and I wasn't sending it.

All the keystore and truststore generation is perfect. This is the "final" solution (using Spring Web Services):

```
  //
  // Spring Config

  // Inject messageSender() into a WebServiceTemplate or,
  // Have a class that extends from WebServiceGatewaySupport

  @Bean
  public HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender() throws Exception {
    HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender = new BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender(username, password);
    messageSender.setTrustManagers(trustManagersFactoryBean().getObject());
    messageSender.setKeyManagers(keyManagersFactoryBean().getObject());
    return messageSender;
  }

  @Bean
  public TrustManagersFactoryBean trustManagersFactoryBean() {
    TrustManagersFactoryBean trustManagersFactoryBean = new TrustManagersFactoryBean();
    trustManagersFactoryBean.setKeyStore(trustStore().getObject());
    return trustManagersFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public KeyManagersFactoryBean keyManagersFactoryBean() {
    KeyManagersFactoryBean keyManagersFactoryBean = new KeyManagersFactoryBean();
    keyManagersFactoryBean.setKeyStore(keyStore().getObject());
    keyManagersFactoryBean.setPassword(keyStorePassword);
    return keyManagersFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public KeyStoreFactoryBean trustStore() {
    KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStoreFactoryBean = new KeyStoreFactoryBean();
    keyStoreFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("truststore.jks")); // Located in src/main/resources
    keyStoreFactoryBean.setPassword(trustStorePassword);
    return keyStoreFactoryBean;
  }

  @Bean
  public KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStore() {
    KeyStoreFactoryBean keyStoreFactoryBean = new KeyStoreFactoryBean();
    keyStoreFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("keystore.jks"));
    keyStoreFactoryBean.setPassword(keyStorePassword);
    return keyStoreFactoryBean;
  }
```

---

```
// You might need org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-support in order to
// have HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender
public final class BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender extends HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender {
  private String b64Creds;

  public BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender(String username, String password) {
    b64Creds = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }

  @Override
  protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, String.format("Basic %s", b64Creds));
    super.prepareConnection(connection);
  }
}
```

---

Refer also to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46811171/4695271) — also asked by myself O:)

Hope this can help someone in the future. It took me a while to put up together everything.