# Spring WS Client — Authentication using KeyStore/TrustStore and Credentials (Basic Auth)

Tags: web-services, authentication, spring-ws

I have a Spring WS client that needs to authenticate using a keystore/trustore combination and also via basic auth.

This is the relevant Spring config that I currently have:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringWSConfig {
  @Bean
  public Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller() {
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
    marshaller.setPackagesToScan("io.shido.credit.domain");
    return marshaller;
  }

  @Bean
  public WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate() throws Exception {
    final WebServiceTemplate template = new WebServiceTemplate(jaxb2Marshaller(), jaxb2Marshaller());
    template.setDefaultUri("https://domain.tld/SVC/data");
    //template.setMessageSenders(new WebServiceMessageSender[]{ messageSender(), messageSender2() });
    //template.setInterceptors(new ClientInterceptor[] { wss4jSecurityInterceptor() });
    template.setMessageSender(messageSender());
    return template;
  }

  @Bean
  public HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender() throws Exception {
    HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender = new HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender();
    messageSender.setTrustManagers(trustManagersFactoryBean().getObject()); // set the trust store(s)
    messageSender.setKeyManagers(keyManagersFactoryBean().getObject()); // set the key store(s)
    return messageSender;
  }
```

This works for the keystore/trustore part. I'm able to do the SSL handshake successfully, but right now I'm getting an **HTTP 401 (Unauthorized)**. So I tried:

- To have multiple `senders`; one of them `HttpComponentsMessageSender` with the username and password on it...but it doesn't work
- To configure a `ClientInterceptor` with some `Wss4jSecurityInterceptor` config/settings...also doesn't work
- To use a sender that inherits from `HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender`, add a `username` and `password` fields, overwrite `prepareConnection` and set `connection.setRequestProperty` to use an `Authorization` header. This time I get an **HTTP 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

Any clues how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating a new class and injecting it as a `message sender` in the Spring's `WebServiceTemplate`. That solves the `HTTP 401 (Unauthorized)` — don't quite remember about the `HTTP 405 (Method Not Allowed)`.

```
@Bean
public HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender() throws Exception {
  HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender messageSender = new BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender(username, password);
  // ...
  return messageSender;
}
```

---

```
// You might need org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-support in order to
// have HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender
public final class BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender extends HttpsUrlConnectionMessageSender {
  private String b64Creds;

  public BasicAuthHttpsConnectionMessageSender(String username, String password) {
    b64Creds = Base64.getUrlEncoder().encodeToString((username + ":" + password).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
  }

  @Override
  protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    connection.setRequestProperty(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, String.format("Basic %s", b64Creds));
    super.prepareConnection(connection);
  }
}
```

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47046804/4695271) also for more info. Both are related (if not almost the same).